# Import a .so file from Django

Tags: python, c++, django

I have a C++ code

```
#include <Python.h>

static PyObject* py_veripy(PyObject* self, PyObject* args){

    /* BODY */
    return Py_BuildValue("i", 1);

}

// Bind Python function names to our C functions
static PyMethodDef veripy_methods[] = {
    {"veripy", py_veripy, METH_VARARGS},
    {NULL, NULL}
};

// Python calls this to let us initialize our module
extern "C" void initveripy(){
    (void) Py_InitModule("veripy", veripy_methods);
}
```

I have compiled it and created a .so file. I want to use this library in one of my Django app, but I am confused as to where to keep this library in my directory. I have tried keeping it with the code, obviously, but it doesn't seem to find it. I found [this](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/252650-making-importing-and-using-a-c-library-in-python-linux-version/) tutorial similar to my case, but the C++ code there doesn't have Python.h included in it. Please help.

Comment: Did you try using Cython? It will create a .so file with it. Have you tried it?

Comment: I have a .so file, I just wanted to know where to place it in my Django app directory. Also, I can import the .so file in python.

Comment: .so files gets tricky while installation. Can you put your directory structure? And what have you tried with it?

Comment: It turns out that the code works when i keep the .so file within the app folder beside the views.py file. Sorry, my bad, I was confused because I'm new to Django.

Comment: No problem. Would you mind if I write an answer for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we can't see the directory structure of your library, it seems that you must be missing the `import` conditions in your modules e.g. putting `__init__.py` at places or writing correct extension for the output module.

Well, as you have solved your problem by **puting .so file within the app folder beside the `views.py` file**, here's a little more tip for you.

If for any reason Python interpreter fails to recognize .so module, say `filename.so`, you need to place a `filename.py` file right beside it with the following content

```
def __bootstrap__():
   global __bootstrap__, __loader__, __file__
   import sys, pkg_resources, imp
   __file__ = pkg_resources.resource_filename(__name__,'filename.so')
   __loader__ = None; del __bootstrap__, __loader__
   imp.load_dynamic(__name__,__file__)
__bootstrap__()
```

This ensures the correct import of `filename.so`

Prefer using Cython for interfacing with C/C++ or FORTRAN. It's cross platform. As you would know that .so files are only for linux/mac.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you should create a setup.py file, so that this compiles your library and put it somewhere.

For example, here an example of a setup.py file that I used for a personal project:

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension

setup(
      name="modulename", 
      version="0.1",
      test_suite = "nose.collector",
      author='<author name>',
      setup_requires=['nose>=0.11'],
      description="My super module implementation",
      ext_modules=[Extension("modulename", ["src/mysupermodule.c"])]
)
```

This will generate a 'build/' folder, but of course you can find more about setuptools on [the official documentation page](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html).